# How to increment the string value using for loop? Suppose my first value is "Project1" and then i want the second value as "project2" and so on

Tags: java

Given string is String[] s1={"Project1"} Using for loop I want to change s1 value from "Project1" into "Project2" on my next iteration. As the loop continuous the project value should get increment.Can someone help to solve this problem as am new to java and selenium.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `int` in conjunction with string concatenation:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    String projectName = "Project" + i;
    // use projectName here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String str = "Project";
int HighestNumber; //set the bound for the number of projects you want
for(int i = 0;i<HighestNumber; i++)
{
    System.out.println(str + toString(i));
}
```

in case you don't want to set a limit you can use

```
int i = 0; // or 1
while(true)
{
    i++;
    System.out.println(str + toString(i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to set that highestnumber value to infinity? Value should keep on incrementing without any limitation.

Comment: I edited the answer so it will be more clear to what I mean with the while(true) loop

Comment: This solution will generate "Project1234567891011...", because of str=str+i

Comment: sorry my bad, fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] s1={"Project1"};
for(int i=2; i<n;i++) // n is how many you have to increase the project value
{
    s1[0]= "Project"+String.valueOf(i);
    System.out.println(s1[0]); 
}
```

on 1st iteration i will print Project2

2nd iteration Project3

2nd iteration Project4..........